# UNION show for getting all fields in DB, information_schema not available

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get all the fields in a database, `information_schema` is not available.

However, I can show the fields of a single table using

`show columns from table`

How can I add another show command?
I tried `UNION`, but it gives me syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to look at JOIN-ing tables together, ideally through the foreign keys if they exist for each of the tables in your database. 
For example

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id;
```

The SELECT * is a lazy way of saying display every column in each table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question, but if you wants to list column names about a table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your table name';
```

You can change WHERE condition as you like.  Other info columns are available.